# How to get the whole node in one element with PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have xml file like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <List>
        <Name>
            <ID>
                <UID123>
                    <USERID>123</USERID>
                    <TechType>4G</TechType>
                    <INIT>
                        <String>Storage</String>
                        <Int>0011</Int>
                    </INIT>
                    <Fact>Default</Fact>
                </UID123>
                <UID456>
                    <USERID>456</USERID>
                    <TechType>4G</TechType>
                    <INIT>
                        <String>Storage</String>
                        <Int>0011</Int>
                    </INIT>
                    <Fact>Default</Fact>
                </UID456>
            </ID>
        </Name>     
    </List>
```

I want to get the whole node in element `UID123` . I tried this way, but the information that I got only  this:

```
USERID            : 8594
TechType          : 4G
INIT              : INIT
OPTANE            : OPTANE
Fact              : Defaults
```

The value from this node, I dont got it.

```
    <INIT>
        <String>Storage</String>
        <Int>0011</Int>
    </INIT>
```

Anyone can help me please. Thank you.

```
    [xml]$Read = Get-Content -Path "D:\List.xml"
    $Info = $Read.List.Name.ID.UID123
    $Info | Out-File .\Output.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data for any of the tags within the xml by using `GetElementsByTagName`. Following is how it should be used.

**SAVE AND READ NEEDED XML**

```
$info = $Read.GetElementsByTagName("UID123").OuterXml
$info | Out-File C:\temp\new.xml

[xml]$NewRead = Get-Content C:\temp\new.xml
$NewRead.UID123
```

Comment: But the format output is different. I can not read the output file

Comment: Thank yo for your advice, but my expectation the output file should be xml file. :(

Comment: I dont understand... GetElementsByTagName with InnerXml gives you the xml, does that not work? What's the issue with that? Can you provide what you expect the output file should be

Comment: I tried with this GetElementsByTagName with InnerXml . But once I want to read the output file, it return this error `Cannot convert value ....`` Error: "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node.`

Comment: If you are looking to save it and then read it in later, then you'll have to save the outerXml instead of inner to load the parent `DocumentNode`. @SBR let me know if this helps